# Xpath or xquery and test the order

Tags: xpath, xquery

Using SoapUI (great tool for WS by the way), I have the following xml result :

```
<code>c</code>
<code>b</code>
<code>a</code>
```

For this sample above, i would like to test the code value are order asc. Of course, for this sample the test will fail like excepted.

Any solution with xquery or xpath (i can use groovy inside the test if necessary)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Little tip: just highlight your XML and code snippets in the editor, and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar. It'll nicely format the XML (or code), and you won't have to mess around with replacing "<" with "&lt;" and so forth - plus the stuff gets nicely syntax highlighted, too!

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for an XPath 2.0 / XQuery solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use** (XQuery or XPath 2.0):

```
not(code[. > following-sibling::code])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways:

```
empty(
  for $x at $p in code
  where ($x > code[$p + 1])
  return $x
)
```

and

```
deep-equal(for $x in code order by $x return $x/data(.), code/data(.))
```

But Dimitre's answer seems the cleanest.